# Adding Child (Comment) part to every Parent (Answer) Component in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import moment from 'moment'
import Avatar from '../../components/Avatar/Avatar'
import { useSelector, useDispatch} from 'react-redux'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'
import { deleteAnswer } from '../../actions/question'

const DisplayAnswer = ( { question, handleShare }  ) => {

    const User = useSelector((state) => (state.currentUserReducer))
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const { id } = useParams()
    
    const [button, setButton] = useState(false);

    const handleDelete = (answerId, noOfAnswers) => {
        dispatch(deleteAnswer(id, answerId, noOfAnswers-1))
    }

    const handleComment = (e) => {
        setButton(!button)
        alert(e.target.id)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {   
                question.answer.map( (ans) => (
                    <div className="display-ans" key={ans._id}>
                        <p>{ans.answerBody}</p>
                        <div className="question-actions-user">
                            <div>
                                <button type="button" onClick={handleShare}>Share</button>
                                {          
                                    User?.result?._id === ans?.userId && (
                                        <button type='button' onClick={ () => handleDelete(ans._id, question.noOfAnswers) }>Delete</button>
                                    )
                                }

                                <div>
                                        
                                </div>

                                <button id = {ans._id} type='button' onClick = { (e) => handleComment(e) }> Add Comment </button>

                                {
                                    button && 
                                    (
                                        <div id = {ans._id}>
                                            <textarea rows='5' cols='30'> </textarea> <br />
                                            <button type='button'> Post </button>
                                        </div>
                                    )
                                }
                                
                            </div>

                            <div>
                                <p>answered { moment(ans.answeredOn).fromNow()}</p>
                                <Link to={`/Users/${ans.userId}`} className='user-link' style={{color:'#0086d8'}}>
                                    <Avatar backgroundColor="lightgreen" px='8px' py='5px' borderRadius='4px'>{ans.userAnswered.charAt(0).toUpperCase()}</Avatar>
                                    <div>
                                        {ans.userAnswered}
                                    </div>
                                </Link>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                   </div> 

                ))
            }
        </div>


    )
}

export default DisplayAnswer
```

I want to add a comment part under every answer
to do that i added a " Add Comment " button under every Answer and i have a button click on that button

and what i want is whenever the button is clicked the addcomment (textbox) should be added under it

but when i click the button the addcomment (textbox) is getting added under every answer

like if 10 answers are their then Addcommment box is getting added under every 10 answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is only a single `button` state that ***all*** the mapped answers render a button for. A simple solution would be to instead store the answer id of the answer you want to add a comment for.

Example:

```
const DisplayAnswer = ({ question, handleShare }) => {
  ...

  const [commentId, setCommentId] = useState(null); // <-- initially null

  ...

  const handleComment = (e) => {
    setCommentId(e.target.id); // <-- set answer id here
    alert(e.target.id);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {question.answer.map((ans) => (
        <div className="display-ans" key={ans._id}>
          <p>{ans.answerBody}</p>
          <div className="question-actions-user">
            <div>
              ...

              <button
                id={ans._id}
                type="button"
                onClick={handleComment}
              >
                Add Comment
              </button>

              {commentId === and._id && ( // <-- conditionally render match by id
                <div id={ans._id}>
                  <textarea rows="5" cols="30" />
                  <br />
                  <button type="button">Post</button>
                </div>
              )}
            </div>

            ...
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

When the "Post comment" button is clicked and the entered comment is handled don't forget to also set the `commentId` value back to null to conditionally hide the input.

Comment: Thanks,  i looked all over the internet to find the solution but couldn't find it, thankyou for your help it's working now

Comment: can you inshort explain me what i was doing incorrect or like why wasn't that working

Comment: @VinayJain Sure. There's only one `const [button, setButton] = useState(false);` state and for each `question.answer` that is mapped they all reference the same single `button` state to conditionally render a textarea, i.e. the `button && <textarea />. When `button` is truthy each answer rendered a textarea.

Answer (score 0):

Each answer must have his own 'state' to display his own textArea, so you have to extract the code of the 'answer' in a new Answer component, and render a new  component in the map method.

Each Answer will thus use a "useState" with a "[isTextAreaVisible, setIsTextAreaVisible] = useState(false);" state.